# Keep returning you are ready whether user input is y or n

Tags: java, if-statement, input

```
    import java.util.Scanner;



    public class Two {
public static void main (String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean userReady=false;

    do{
        System.out.println("y/n")
        String userinput = input.nextLine();
        if (userinput.equals("y")){
            userReady = true;
        }else if (userinput.equals("n")){
            userReady = false;  
        }
    }while (userReady = false);
    System.out.println("You are ready!");
}
```

}

result is always "You are ready" im sure its a super simple fix that i just cant get my head around...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running `while(userReady = false);` instead of `while(userReady == false);`. This is not checking for condition, just assigning a value.

Answer (score 2):

Because `System.out.println("You are ready!");` is not under any condition or loop.

Its a separate last statement.

Comment: it wasnt looping for me in the first place turns out the }while (userReady = false); needed to be "==" instead of "=" then the program started to loop when i entered "n"

Answer (score 0):

Just move the print in the condition where you press `y`.

```
public class Two {
   public static void main (String args[]){
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     boolean userReady=false;

     do{
        System.out.println("y/n")
        String userinput = input.nextLine();
        if (userinput.equals("y")){
            userReady = true;
            System.out.println("You are ready!");
        }else if (userinput.equals("n")){
            userReady = false;  
        }
     }while (userReady = false);
  }
}
```

Comment: it wasnt looping for me in the first place turns out the }while (userReady = false); needed to be "==" instead of "=" then the program started to loop when i entered "n"

Comment: That always get's me to :)